# Stata foreach loop

Tags: stata

I am trying to execute a Stata `foreach` loop, but I keep encountering an error that the variable does not exist even though when I look in my data editor it does exist, and I am capable of looking at it using `list some_column`. This is what I am doing:

```
foreach x of varlist some_column1 some_column2{
            list x
 }
```

Could someone help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking Stata to list the *variable* `x`, which clearly you don't have. What you really want is to `list` the contents of the *local macro* `x`. To do that, enclose it within appropriate quote marks.

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

foreach x of varlist weight mpg {
    list `x' in 1/10
}
```

See the manual: **[P] macro**. `help foreach` is filled with examples.

Comment: Perhaps `list` here is just providing an example. If your interest really is in `list`ing two or more variables, don't use a loop, as `list` will provide a simultaneous listing of several variables.